# how to Apply Master Pages By Folder in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have folder called Email which contains 20 aspx pages I am trying to apply master page to this email folder through web.config

i Got following error
The relative virtual path 'MasterPage.Master' is not allowed here.

code in web.config

Please help in this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use an application-relative path, like `~/Email/MasterPage.Master`

Comment: I doesnt give any error if i try your path.But it nerver inherits master page.

Comment: @kosuri: Maybe there's a problem with your pages, can you show a sample of one?